# Update Google Play service in Google API Emulator 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am using latest android studio V2.0.When I using emulator with Google API_23.
[image]

While running my SocialLoginDemo app in emulator it gives prompt to update Google play Services. In which I integrate *SignIn with Google Account* functionality.

[image]

When I am click on `UPDATE` button , `Google play Services` is not updating.
I already configure my gmail account in emulator. 
What I need to update it?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem before. I fixed this by changing a line in my build.gradle file

from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using newer play services version than you have in your emulator. So you have 2 options:

1. Downgrade your play services version in app (as gerardnimo suggested)
2. Update your play services in emulator.

Since Google introduced [Google Play Store images](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#26-0) in Android SDK Tools 26.0.0. Now emulators can be created with Google Play Store already installed.

From 26.0.3

> - Adds a new tab in the extended window for Google Play Store images that displays the Play Services version and a button to check for updates to Play Services.

[image: emulator settings]